# QTablewidget header column background color is not getting set

Tags: qt, qt-designer, pyside6

I am using pyside6 and python3.10. Trying to set background color of the header in QTableWidget using below snippet. It was not appearing as I expect.

```
@qtc.Slot()
    def showStraddleTable(self, option_chain_df):
        self.tableWidget_oi.setRowCount(option_chain_df.shape[0])
        self.tableWidget_oi.setColumnCount(option_chain_df.shape[1])
        print(Utils.getBackGroundColor("CE"))
        print(Utils.getBackGroundColor("PE"))
        self.tableWidget_oi.horizontalHeaderItem(3).setBackground(Utils.getBackGroundColor("CE"))
        self.tableWidget_oi.horizontalHeaderItem(6).setBackground(Utils.getBackGroundColor("PE"))

        column_font = qtg.QFont()
        column_font.setBold(True)
        for row in range(option_chain_df.shape[0]):
            for col in range(option_chain_df.shape[1]):
                item = option_chain_df.iloc[row, col]
                if isinstance(item, qtw.QWidget):
                    self.tableWidget_oi.setCellWidget(row, col, item)
                else:
                    self.tableWidget_oi.setItem(row, col, QTableWidgetItem(str(item)))
                    if self.tableWidget_oi.item(row,3) :
                        self.tableWidget_oi.item(row, 3).setFont(column_font)
                    if self.tableWidget_oi.item(row,6):
                        self.tableWidget_oi.item(row,6).setFont(column_font)
                    if self.tableWidget_oi.item(row, 10):
                        self.tableWidget_oi.item(row, 10).setFont(column_font)

        
        self.tableWidget_oi.setColumnHidden(12, True)
        self.tableWidget_oi.setColumnHidden(13, True)
        self.tableWidget_oi.setShowGrid(False)

        
        table_height = 40 * self.tableWidget_oi.rowCount()
        self.frame_oi_body.setMinimumHeight(table_height)
```

In the above snippet, bold font was set as expected. But background color
is not displayed as per the code. Not sure what is wrong in my code snippet.

```
        print(Utils.getBackGroundColor("CE"))
        print(Utils.getBackGroundColor("PE"))
        self.tableWidget_oi.horizontalHeaderItem(3).setBackground(Utils.getBackGroundColor("CE"))
        self.tableWidget_oi.horizontalHeaderItem(6).setBackground(Utils.getBackGroundColor("PE"))
```

This was printing expected QColor object as like below. But not getting set in my header background. Please help me on this issue.

```
PySide6.QtGui.QColor.fromRgbF(0.564706, 0.933333, 0.564706, 1.000000)
PySide6.QtGui.QColor.fromRgbF(0.996078, 0.647059, 0.000000, 1.000000)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre].